# Match the object key value to an value from an array

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following list of words in an array

```
var customerAlert = ['IsCustomerAlert', 'CustomerAlertTitle', 'CustomerAlertShortDescription', 'CustomerAlertLongDescription','CustomerAlertMoreURL'];
```

I have an object that looks like the following

```
   var obj = {
      "Primary Key": "0",
      "title": "",
      "show_csr": "",
      "IsCustomerAlert": "",
      "CustomerAlertTitle": "",
      "CustomerAlertShortDescription": "",
      "CustomerAlertLongDescription": "",
      "CustomerAlertMoreURL": ""
    }
```

My objective is go through the object and look for the key values as specified in the array and if this returns true, check if this key has an empty value in the object and if it does append "null" to it dynamically.

My current thought process is

```
for (var key in obj){
   if(customerAlert.match(Regex(key)) && obj[key] === ""){
         obj[key] = "null";
   }
}
```

Is there a better declarative way or imperative way to achieve this and also unsure of the Regex to use for matching the values?

Comment: why are you suing a Regex?

Comment: i am using Regex for a strict matching to the word from object, just my thought process right now though

Comment: Just use the [hasOwnProperty method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need to use regexp in such case. Use `Array.indexOf` method:

```
for (var key in obj){
   if (customerAlert.indexOf(key) !== -1 && obj[key] === "") {
         obj[key] = "null";
   }
}
```

Comment: @Dalorzo, `customerAlert` is an array, and `Array.indexOf` is an array method

Comment: yes i did think of that, but remember if key = title its going to return a -1 when it shouldn't. I want a strict matching to the words in the array

Comment: so for example condition should only pass if the key value is "CustomerAlertTitle" and its value is ""

Comment: @RajPowar, your explanations are contradictory: "for the key values as specified in the array and if this returns true, check if this key has an empty value in the object" -  though you are saying "I want a strict matching"

Comment: "if key="title" its going to return a -1 when it shouldn't " - title is NOT in array , don't you think?

Comment: my apologizes i misread !== -1, is saw it as === -1 long day here :), my apologizes again